# How to insert single contact multiple times in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am using Salescloud Order object in my journey as an event source. Entry condition: Whenever an order is created.I am inserting contact in my journey. Idea is to send an email to the associated contact whenever a new order is created. The DE created in MC do reflect the order entries whenever a new order is created. However once a contact enters into the journey, he do not re enters again , even if a new order is created for the same contact in the Salescloud. The same contact can place multiple orders and hence multiple confirmation mail from JB is what i am looking for. Any ideas to implement this?

Refer to the screen shot attached. [image: DE created in MC as a aprt of entry event]

[image: JB Interaction]

Although DE shows 5 entries, only 3 unique contacts entered the journey. I want all the five enteries in my JB interaction(i.e 5 emails). 
Thanks

Comment: Is re-entry allowed in your Event?

Comment: Select contact re-entry mode to `Re-entry anytime`.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the entry mode to 'Re-entry anytime'. The Entry mode interface is somewhat buried in the new Lightning UI. From the Interaction Canvas, click on the **cog icon** in the left panel next to the Interaction version that you are editing.

[image: changing entry mode]

This will open a new page listing the options below (why an entire new page is required for this I have no idea)...

- No re-entry
- Re-entry anytime
- Re-entry only after exiting

Select **No re-entry** if contacts may never enter the Interaction again after entering it the first time.

Select **Re-entry at any time** if Contacts may enter the Interaction multiple times before exiting. That is, a Contact can be moving through a single Interaction more than once.

Select **Re-entry only after exiting** if Contacts must exit the Interaction first before they are eligible to re-enter it.

Comment: Doesn't High Water Mark (HWM) allows only net new records to be injected in a Journey. How are we bypassing HWM issues here. TIA

Comment: Yes, you would need to create another record for the Contact in your Event Source DE (assuming you are using Composite Keys in your DE), or overwrite the Event Source DE (which will reset the high watermark).